# APScheduler ImportError: No module named apscheduler.schedulers.background

Tags: apscheduler

I have APScheduler-3.5.1 and Python 2.6.6 in staging environment.

I am getting an error while running APScheduler:

> ImportError: No module named apscheduler.schedulers.background

Same code is working fine on Dev environment with Python 2.7.5.
I tried installing on python 2.6 (staging) with pip2.6

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "check_executor.py", line 22, in <module>
    from apscheduler.schedulers.background import BackgroundScheduler
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/apscheduler/schedulers/background.py", line 5, in <module>
    from apscheduler.schedulers.base import BaseScheduler
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/apscheduler/schedulers/base.py", line 19, in <module>
    from apscheduler.jobstores.memory import MemoryJobStore
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/apscheduler/jobstores/memory.py", line 4, in <module>
    from apscheduler.util import datetime_to_utc_timestamp
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/apscheduler/util.py", line 141
    values = {k: int(v or 0) for k, v in values.items()}
```

I tried APScheduler-2.1.2 but I get import error and the old one would not work for my requirements. Is python 2.6.6 version supported or do i need to account for anything more?

Comment: I am using virtualenv with python 2.7 as a workaround to it. APScheduler works fine there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python 2.6 support was dropped in 3.1.0, as noted [here](https://github.com/agronholm/apscheduler/blob/master/docs/versionhistory.rst#310). Python 2.6 reached its end of life in October 29, 2013.